# Looking for better method names

Tags: java, oop, method-names

In a code review, I am facing a class that includes the following method pair:

```
getOrCreateXXXFor(YYY)
getXXXFor(YYY)
```

(XXX and YYY are two business logic types.) I'm not sure whether these are the *ideal* names.

The first is indeed related to the Singleton pattern but with a parameter and

- returns an object, if it exists or
- creates and returns it, if it doesn't exist.

The second one

- returns the same object as the first method, but only, if it exists
- throws an `Exception`, if it does not exist.

I'm thinking about whether they should be renamed. Do you have any better suggestions?

---

**[EDIT]**
To be more specific:

- the names should be short and concise descriptions of what happens (without the need for reading the docs)
- the relation of the two methods should be preserved by the names

In short, it should result in a clean API.
To give things a good understandable name is a central part of software craftsmanship.  The topic is as little opinion based as sorting arrays.

Comment: How do you define an "ideal" name?

Comment: are they returning different objects?

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid Which website? (Honest question).

Comment: This is basically a flyweight pattern. Why do you not provide a `createOrGet` and `contains` method?

Comment: why should the users call a method which could throw an exception, when there is a method that will create the object for him instead of throwing an exception? your problem sounds like it can be solved using the singleton or flyweight pattern

Comment: @PhilippSander: Because some people would rather their code be correct than that it never throw any exception?

Comment: @SoylentGreen Probably because it's OT for SO.

Comment: @ruakh "Correct" is nebulous, what's correct depends on the situation.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Yes, absolutely; that's actually my point. (I was replying to the implication that the correct thing is *always* to call `getOrCreate` rather than simply `get`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Singleton-Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and/or the [Flyweight-Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern)

I would recommend implementing it as Singleton and provide an exists method.

```
public class SingletonDemo {
    private static volatile SingletonDemo instance = null;

    private SingletonDemo() {       }

    public static SingletonDemo getInstance() {
            if (instance == null) {
                    synchronized (SingletonDemo .class){
                            if (instance == null) {
                                    instance = new SingletonDemo ();
                            }
                    }
            }
            return instance;
    }

    public boolean exists() {
        return instance != null;
    }
}
```